# How to use qnorm function in R with non-symmetric values? For exapmle, P(-2 < z < z0) = 0.9710

Tags: r, statistics

I know how to find the z-knot value with symmetry using the qnorm function, like when trying to find P(-z0 <= z <= 0) = 0.2967

```
tail = (1 - 0.2967)/2 
qnorm(tail)
```

But how do we use it for something like P(-2 < z < z0) = 0.9710 ?

Can we even use qnorm with non-symmetric stuff?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: P(a <= x <= b) = P(x <= b) - P(x <= a)

Comment: I finally figured it out thanks to your help. The answer is: z0 =  qnorm((1 -0.9710) - pnorm(-2))  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: z0 = qnorm((1 -0.9710) - pnorm(-2))